# Separating items inside a list

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a list of items inside a Flatlist and I want to separate them with a point (‧) like this:

[image: Eg]

I have something like this: ([snack.expo.io/@abranhe/flatlist-separator](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/flatlist-separator))

```
<FlatList
  data={[ 'foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'word' ]}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item} ‧ </Text>}
  horizontal={true}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Unfortunately, it will add an extra point (‧) at the end of the items.

```
foo ‧ bar ‧ hello ‧ world ‧
```

Is there a simple way to remove the last separator from the list?

```
foo ‧ bar ‧ hello ‧ world
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you take all the list items at once and make a whole `string` or do want to iterate over them ?

Comment: No I want to iterate over them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[ItemSeparatorComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.48/flatlist#itemseparatorcomponent)**

```
<FlatList
  data={data}
  horizontal
  renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Text> ‧ </Text>}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`renderItem` prop has a property called `index` which tells you the index of the current rendering item. You can check that to see if it is the last item.

**Example**

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.someData}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <Text>{(index !== (this.state.someData.length -1) ? `${item} -` : item)} </Text>
  )}
  horizontal={true}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it didn't work for me, check it out: https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/flatlist-separator-eg

Comment: @CarlosAbraham fixed the example. there was a typo